# How to Fix Seq2Seq Model Output Delay Due to Pre-Padded and CrossEntropyLoss ignore_index in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, lstm, padding

I'm encountering a challenging issue with sequence generation in PyTorch, specifically with regard to the handling of pre-padded sequences and the behaviour of the CrossEntropyLoss "ignore_index" parameter.

I'm working on a seq2seq model and preparing my target sequences with pre-padding (padding at the beginning) before feeding them into the model. The CrossEntropyLoss is setup to ignore the padding indices by using the "ignore_index" parameter to prevent padding from contributing to the loss.

However, this practice is resulting in an unexpected learning behaviour, rather than starting sequence generation immediately after the start-of-sequence ("sos") token, my model is showing a tendency to generate a delayed output. Essentially, it is generating random tokens in place of the initial padding and only later begins to generate the expected sequence elements.

For example:

- Target and Training sequence: [pad, pad, pad, pad, sos, 3, 9, 4, 3, eos]
- Desired generation during Inference: [sos, 3, 9, 4, 3, eos]
- Model generation during inference: [sos, 6, 4, 9, sos, 3, 9, 4, 3, eos]

The target sequence starts with several padding tokens ("pad"), followed by the sequence starting at the "sos" token, and ending with an "eos" token. My expectation was for the model to learn to ignore the padding and start generating meaningful output just after the "sos" token is fed in during inference.

Instead, the model fills the initial positions corresponding to the ignored padding, with random tokens and only starts to generate the proper sequence partway through. It seems as though the ignored leading padding is causing the model to push back its generation of valid sequence elements.

How can I adjust my model or loss function to correctly encourage immediate generation following the "sos" token and avoid the influence of initial padding on the generation process?

What I've Tried:

I explored using post-padding, which didn't have this issue. However, pre-padding seems to have given better results in my experience ignoring the delayed response issue, so I'm inclined to stick with it to test how well it performs after this issue is solved.

I've also come across references to "pack_padded_sequence" in my research, however, it seems incompatible with my current PyTorch setup, which utilizes "torch.set_default_device('cuda')". Thus, I've yet to determine its suitability for my needs and would prefer other options that align with my existing implementation, which leverages certain features I prefer to keep using which are incompatible with it.